# Forgot my name, can you help me?

Tags: riddle, story, cipher

***MaDe tHe rIdDle MySelF AnD dOn'T BeLiEve ME.***

> I got a name that you can't guess,
>    Solve this riddle with some of your guess and other with your best.
>   There are no roads to my home,
>   not even horses or even a train,
>    the only route to my house is the thing used in 100 BC.
>   I live with my strict father,
>   if you found my father you can find me,
>   But don't think this is so easy.
>   My father got his name from a famous writer,
>   named *FARXPVQ FRYENUP.*
>   ...................................................***-Zemflez Texleo***

Comment: Read it nicely, it 'could be' complex.

Comment: Your name is clearly Zemflez Texleo, you even signed off on the riddle!

Comment: @GordonAllocman Do you think I would name myself something like tha?.

Comment: They didn't use horses or roads in 100 BC?

Comment: @paste Just a line, go deep.

Comment: @VaibhavTech I didn't bring my scuba gear

Comment: Wonder if "100 BC" = CBC = Cipher Block Chaining

Comment: @paste get you scuba gear, the ocean is very deep. It is necessary.

Comment: You wrote a long useless riddle and now you won't select an answer. Is your name what you wanted for an answer? If you're not satisfied with my explanation, maybe you shouldn't have put the text that gave off the answer in bold letters. Your riddle was just too easy. Deal with it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Vaibhav Pathak == rot22('Zemflez Texleo')

Comment: Please edit your answer to include your reasoning as to why you think this solution is correct.

Comment: so that's why you downvoted?

Comment: this might not be the answer, but the guy said he forgot his name, i felt he needed to be reminded.

Comment: @SLowLoris you should give the complete answer. You just the computer and deciphered it.

Comment: lol, i think he found the answer way easier than you thought and you couldn't handle this :)

Comment: there is no complete answer, the FARXPVQ FRYENUP part was too obvious and i just took the part in bold, ran it through http://www.rot13.com/ and pressed down on the selectbox until the output was readable. much like any other bruteforce activity. now please upvote me before i upvote myself :P

Comment: Not sure how this answer got 14 upvotes.  It's a *terrible* answer.  It doesn't explain how any of the riddle is relevant to the solution.  It's just a guess unless it shows how everything in the riddle is relevant to the solution.  I could just as easily say the solution is **Pucvbup Junbue** because it is rot16(Zemflez Texleo).  Without anything to explain/back up your answer, it is just as ridiculous as mine.

Comment: You're totally right, in my opinion the riddle is badly written and i can't find any relation between it and my answer, other than op's username. Yet thank you for your opinion and downvote

Answer (score 10):

*WIP*

Your father is named after

> CHARLES DICKENS. Taking the name `FARXPVQ FRYENUP` and using a ROT13 cipher gives SNEKCID SELRAHC which is CHARLES DICKENS backwards.

Comment: No!, not even close. This is not the complete answer. Charles Dickens is just a hint, find my name man.

Comment: But you got that right.

Comment: No! How could you know that Charles Dickens was a strict father, even if you know, the riddle says the father got his name from Charles Dickens.

Answer (score 9):

Your name is

> Paul.
>  This comes from Charles Dickens novel Dombey and Son, where both father and son share the same name - Paul.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, since this doesn't have a chosen answer, I'll choose to explain how SLow Loris got to the answer in a verbose way.

The signature, at the end of the riddle is "Zemflez Texleo".
We're going to change this signature in a simple, yet effective way.
Take the first letter "Z", and look at this alphabet:
"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".

There are two ways to calculate this:

The first way is to simply count 22 characters to the right of the "Z", starting at the beginning again if you run out of letters.

The second way is to do the same thing, only count to the left 4 characters, jumping back to the end of the alphabet if you run out of characters.

In either of these cases, you simply repeat the same process (22 to the right, or 4 to the left) until all of the letters are replaced.

Credit well and truly goes to SLow Loris, though.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is called a Caesar Cipher, and it's already fairly well-known. Something similar to this would be *perfect* for a question about how the Caesar Cipher works, but it doesn't really answer the question here.

Comment: @Deusovi Thanks! I thought that this would be a good explanation because the said that SLowLoris hadn't given the whole explanation. Definitely agree that it's more of a "Here's how a Caesar's Cipher works", but I thought that it might be the answer that the OP was looking for as it does give a more "complete answer".

Comment: instead of giving another answer maybe you should edit his answer and write these stuff in his answer :)

Comment: The riddle itself is not what I expected to find here, i hope op doesn't take this the wrong way, but if i actually read the text i'd be misled.

Comment: @nim Still learning the format here. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @SLowLoris I agree that it is just a bit difficult to understand.